# Ruby - Mechanize Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, mechanize, require

I can't even get past this stage of my code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri"
require "mechanize"

puts "success"
```

I keep getting in these junctures at custom_require.rb:

```
gem_original_require path
```

and under nokogiri.rb

```
begin
  RUBY_VERSION =~ /(\d+.\d+)/
  require "nokogiri/#{$1}/nokogiri"
rescue LoadError
  require 'nokogiri/nokogiri'
end
```

There's something wrong with my custom_require.rb and nokogiri.rb, I just can't figure out what. And I"m pretty sure my `$PATH` is incorrect... Here's what I get when I run `rvm get stable`

```
/Users/Yoshi/.bash_profile:2:export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Yoshi/.rvm/bin
/Users/Yoshi/.bash_profile:7:PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-[374/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Yoshi/.rvm/bin
```

All these gems are confusing as hell. If it helps I'm running ruby 2.0.0p353, nokogiri 1.6.2.1

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?